# MEF: How to send message from module to host application

Tags: wpf, events, mef, desktop-application

I've got next problem. I have a 3 modules and a host application. How to send an event with params (or command with params) from modules and hadle it in host application or in another module?

Comment: You can add events to interfaces. Add an event to your exported interface and consume it via the interface in the app. Exported types can then publish events through this interface and apps that import these types can subscribe.